# Orbit vs the orbit

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

What is the difference between

> get it into orbit

and

> get it into **the** orbit

Comment: This has been suggested for closure as being based on opinion. I disagree. As the solid answer provided indicates, the two sentences have slightly different meanings. What are we here for if not to elucidate the subtle shadings of meaning available in English.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "into the orbit" is for a *specific* orbit, whereas "into orbit" could be *any* orbit.

> We put the satellite into ***the*** orbit of the International Space Station.

However for a specific *type* of orbit I would use "a".

> We put the satellite into ***a*** geostationary orbit.

But in a general sense, we say

> We put the satellite into orbit.

Comment: I agree, but specifically another object in _the_ orbit of the ISS would be not only at the same distance from the Earth but would be following the same track in a different position on that track. It is possible for a third object to be orbiting at the same same altitude but be crossing over the track of the other two. Obviously the third object could collide with the ISS or the second object.